# Como recorrer los datos de una tabla de bd por medio de LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

tengo el siguiente problema soy nuevo usando LINQ en C# y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
        var empleado = db.Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeID ==numReloj).ToList();
        var ID = empleado[0].ID;
        var employeec = db.Employee_Course.Where(x => x.ID_EMPLEADO == ID).ToList();
        var idcourse = employeec[0].ID_CURSO;
        var cursos = db.Courses.Where(x => x.ID_CURSO == idcourse).ToList();
```

Aqui lo que hace el codigo es tomar en cuenta el numero de reloj del empleado y necesito ver que cursos tiene pero la variable idcourse solo me agarra el primer elemento saben como puedo hacer que se recorra todos los datos de esa tabla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvio que solo te agarra el primer elemento, eso es lo que estás diciendo en employeec[0] -> el hecho de usar `[]` y asignarle un número entre dichos signos, estás diciendo que quieres un elemento específico de un índice.

Reemplaza esto:

```
var idcourse = employeec[0].ID_CURSO;
```

por esto:

```
var idcourseList = employeec.Select(x => x.ID_CURSO).ToList(); // Aquí tendrás todos los ID en una lista de int.
```

Ahora es momento de ver toda la lista de cursos que tengan un ID en la lista que acabamos de definir:

```
var cursos = db.Courses.Where(x => idcourseList.Contains(x.ID_CURSO)).ToList();
```

Finalmente, para recorrer todos los elementos de los cursos, un clásico foreach:

```
foreach(var cursoSimpatico in cursos) 
{
... 
}
```